# UWP file permission?

Tags: .net, windows, uwp, directory, universal

I am making a backup application for UWP. I am trying to make it so it first checks the directory to see if it exists but I am running into errors such that it always returns false.

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo("F:\\ISOs");


        if (d.Exists)
```

I read somewhere that UWP is restricted to file access but I cannot seem to find how to extend permissions. I also heard that Microsoft might be strict in app approval. What do you guys think? I wanted to release to the Microsoft App store so it is more convenient for people.

Comment: One way: Ask user to select a backup location through open folder picker on first app start, also check relevant permissions in appxmanifest. And also there is a way to directly save file in other pre specified location but for this i need to access my pc, which is currently not possible

Comment: Are you using the 'broadFilesystemAccess' capability?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations